# How do I get name and email from Apple sign in?

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing Apple sign in on my iOS app. I want to retrieve the user's name and email on every login.  I think there's a way to do it with the API. I am trying the following URL in Postman, and it always returns a webpage - not any user data.
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=com.greenrobot.endhunger.service&redirect_uri=https://greenrobot.com/&response_type=id_token%20code

Any ideas?

Edit: I am following the instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms

Answer (score 2):

With Sign in with Apple, you only get the email/name on first login. It's your responsibility to then store that information. Source:

> The identification servers return the user status only when the user
> first uses Sign in with Apple with your app. Subsequent attempts don’t
> return any information for this user status, such as after a
> disconnect and reconnect occurs or from other devices.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple

Also: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496

Comment: How do you debug this? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Still I only get the user_identifier. I think you can connect via rest with the user identifier and get the user data.

Comment: You need to go into the Apple account settings and delete the Sign In with Apple association for your app/website. Then the next time you trigger Sign In with Apple It will be considered an initial login and you will get name/email.